# Accordion Dinamico PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes campos:`ID, NomDocumento, Fecha, Url y Mes`. En esta se guardarán los registros agrupados por Mes.

Con estos datos estoy armando un *Accordion* con *Bootstrap4*. Mi idea es que el campo Mes sea el botón y en el panel-body mostrar todos los archivos del mes.

Solo que ahora me muestra un panel por registro, siendo que quiero un panel por mes

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Tarifas";      
  $result = $con->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $id = $row['id_Tarifa'];
      $nombre = $row["tarNombre"];
      $fecha = $row["tarFecha"];
      $url = $row['tarURL'];
      $mes = $row["tarMes"];

      echo "<div class='pnel-group' id='accordion'>
              <div class='panel panel-default'>
                <div class='panel-heading'>
                  <h4 class='panel-title'>
                    <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#collapse".$id."'>".$mes."</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              <div id='collapse".$id."' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
                <div class='panel-body'>".$nombre." - ".$fecha." - ".$url." - ".$mes."</div>
              </div>
            </div>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "Sin información que mostrar";
  }
?>
```

Comment: eso sucede porque estás repitiendo el panel por cada registro en tu tabla

Comment: intenta con una variable digamos $panel fuera de tu bucle y luego solo concatenas el contenido algo como `$panel = "<div class='pnel-group' id='accordion'>;"` luego en tu bucle while concatenas el contenido del panel y fuera del while cierras el div

Comment: @arglez35 Gracias por tu tiempo, lo reviso y te cuento como me va!